# Proving continuity of a linear map from Banach space to its dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

The problem is

---

*Let $V$ be a Banach space over the real field, and let
$T: V \to V^\ast, v \to T_v$
be a linear map between these two Banach spaces that satisfies $T_v(v)\ge 0$ for all $v\in V$. Prove that T is continuous.*

---

I have attempted this question for a while with the guidance of a similar question that have been previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626246/linear-mapping-between-banach-space-and-its-dual). However, the one I'm trying to prove is more general, so I don't have much progress.

I noticed that if we write $T_v(w)$ as $(v,w)$ then it looks similar to an inner product. We have **positivity** from the condition $T_v(v)\ge0$ (but not positive definite). We already have (bi)**linearity**, so it looks similar. This makes me want to have something like Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Combining with the closed graph theorem, the desired result could perhaps be proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need Cauchy-Schwarz, but the Closed Graph Theorem is the way to go. Suppose that $v_n\to v$ and $T_{v_n}\to T$. For any $w\in V$,
$$\tag1
0\leq T_{v_n-w}(v_n-w)=T_{v_n}v_n+T_ww-T_{v_n}w-T_wv_n
$$
Since convergent sequences are bounded, there exists $c>0$ with $\|v_n\|\leq c$ for all $n$. Then
$$
|T_{v_n}v_n-Tv|\leq|(T_{v_n}-T)v_n|+|T(v_n-v)|\leq c\,\|T_{v_n}-T\|+\|T\|\,\|v_n-v\|\to0.
$$
This shows that taking limit in $(1)$ we get
$$\tag2
0\leq Tv+T_ww-Tw-T_wv=T(v-w)-T_w(v-w).
$$
Hence
$$\tag3
T_w(v-w)\leq T(v-w),\qquad\qquad w\in V.
$$
As $V$ is a vector space, $v-w$ rans over all of $V$ as $w$ rans over all of $V$. So we can rewrite $(3)$ as
$$\tag4
T_{v-z}(z)\leq Tz,\qquad\qquad z\in V. 
$$
Using the linearity of $T$ this we again be rewritten as
$$\tag5
(T_v-T)z\leq T_zz,\qquad\qquad z\in V. 
$$
Replacing $w$ with $w/n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$,
$$\tag6
\pm n(T_v-T)\leq T_ww,\qquad\qquad n\in\mathbb Z, w\in V
$$
(note that $T_{w/n}(w/n)=(1/n^2)T_ww$, so the inequality does not change even when $n<0$). The only possibility for $(6)$ to hold is that $T_v-T=0$, which shows that $T_v=T$. Now the Closed Graph Theorem implies that $T$ is bounded.